# Fastest way to find strings in a file

Tags: c#, string

I have a log file that is not more than 10KB  (File size can go up to 2 MB max) and I want to find if atleast one group of these strings occurs in the files. These strings will be on different lines like,

> ACTION:.......
>
> INPUT:...........
>
> RESULT:..........

I need to know atleast if one group of above exists in the file. And I have do this about 100 times for a test (each time log is different, so I have reload and read the log), so I am looking for fastest and bets way to do this.

I looked up in the forums for finding the fastest way, but I dont think my file is too big for those silutions.

Thansk for looking.

Comment: 10 KB is really tiny. I've worked with files too big to fit in memory =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would read it line by line and check the conditions. Once you have seen a group you can quit. This way you don't need to read the whole file into memory. Like this:

```
    public bool ContainsGroup(string file)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            var hasAction = false;
            var hasInput = false;
            var hasResult = false;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (!hasAction)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("ACTION:"))
                        hasAction = true;
                }
                else if (!hasInput)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("INPUT:"))
                        hasInput = true;
                }
                else if (!hasResult)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("RESULT:"))
                        hasResult = true;
                }

                if (hasAction && hasInput && hasResult)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code checks if there is a line starting with ACTION then one with INPUT and then one with RESULT. If the order of those is not important then you can omit the `if () else if ()` checks. In case the line does not start with the strings replace `StartsWith` with `Contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way to do it:

```
StreamReader sr;
string fileContents;

string[] logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Logs");

foreach (string file in logFiles)
{

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
    {

        fileContents = sr.ReadAllText();

        if (fileContents.Contains("ACTION:") || fileContents.Contains("INPUT:") || fileContents.Contains("RESULT:"))
        {
             // Do what you need to here
        }

    }
}
```

You may need to do some variation based on your exact implementation needs - for example, what if the word spans two lines, does the line need to start with the word, etc.

**Added**

Alternate line-by-line check:

```
StreamReader sr;
string[] lines;

string[] logFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Logs");

foreach (string file in logFiles)
{

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file)
    {

        lines = sr.ReadAllLines();

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {        
            if (line.Contains("ACTION:") || line.Contains("INPUT:") || line.Contains("RESULT:"))
            {
                // Do what you need to here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: line by line could occur error. e.g: "AC" "TION" could be on different lines (if the coder has not given any attention on text file) String.Contains is best function to run out.

Comment: @icaptan - yep.  That's why I did the ReadAllText example first, in case the keywords were split across two or more lines.

Comment: If the match text is on two different lines then they will be separated by a new line character and it still wouldn't match. You'd have to strip out any line breaks first.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [How to Read Text From a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx). You might also want to take a look at the [String.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method.

Basically you will loop through all the files. For each file read line-by-line and see if any of the lines contains 1 of your special "Sections".

Answer (score 2):

You don't have much of a choice with text files when it comes to efficiency. The easiest way would definitely be to loop through each line of data. When you grab a line in a string, split it on the spaces. Then match those words to your words until you find a match. Then do whatever you need.

I don't know how to do it in c# but in vb it would be something like...

```
Dim yourString as string
Dim words as string()
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
   yourString = objReader.ReadLine()
   words = yourString.split(" ")
   For Each word in words()
      If Myword = word Then
         do stuff
      End If
   Next
Loop
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This code sample searches for strings in a large text file. The words are contained in a HashSet. It writes the found lines in a temp file.

```
        if (File.Exists(@"temp.txt")) File.Delete(@"temp.txt");

        String line;
        String oldLine = "";
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(largeFileName))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            HashSet<String> hash = new HashSet<String>();
            hash.Add("house");
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"temp.txt"))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    foreach (String str in hash)
                    {
                        if (oldLine.Contains(str))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine(oldLine); 
                            // write the next line as well (optional)
                            sw.WriteLine(line + "\r\n");                                    
                        }
                    }
                    oldLine = line;
                }
            }
        }
```